# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express installation/run problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am running windows 7 and I am trying to get this IDE to work and I am have an incredibly frustrating time making it work.

I am following these instructions

Quick guide:

1. File > New > Project
2. Select "Win32 Console Application"
3. Enter a name and location, select OK
4. In the Win32 Application Wizard under "Application Settings", select "Console Application" and select "Empty project".
5. Click Finish.
6. On the right (or left) hand pane should be Solution Explorer. Open it and right click on the "Source Files" folder and Add > Add New Item.
7. Select C++ file (.cpp)
8. Write code, hit F5 to start with debugging, ctrl+f5 to start without debugging.

After step 4 I get the error, "The platform root directory "E:..........\MSBuild\Microsoft.cpp\v4.0\Platforms" does not exist.

What do I do? I installed it in my E drive, maybe what it wants is on my C drive? It is not possible for me to install it there though because I am using a SSD for my C drive.

Update, I have tried to uninstall and reinstall and then clear my temp folder and then reinstall and then uninstall with the uninstall utility and then reboot and the reinstall and none of that works.

I turning off my firewall and antivirus and installing and running and that did not help at all. Next I am going to format my hard drives and try and install again.

I tried installing the ultimate version and I had the same problem. I have no idea what to do, it seems like I am out of options.

Any ideas?

My best guess now is that I have to manually install the missing files somehow, where can I find those?

I installed Dev C++ and it works fine, should I just continue using this (as far as I can tell superior program) or try and fix Express?

---

### Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express

### The platforms root directory "E:\Program Files                           (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms" does not exist.

OK
---------------------------                                                             The microsoft.cpp part is missing but it exists in the C drive.                                            I copied that over to the E drive and now when I open a project I get a blank screen, if I open older ones it says I need .net framework 4.0 which I do have.

This has to be the worst program I have ever had to deal with, I have played video games in beta that worked better than that.

I think I got this working, I am not sure though.

It appears to be working but I get some strange errors, I am just going to accept this because at least now after an entire weekend I can begin my homework.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Visual Studio doesn't care whether the disk you're installing Visual Studio on is a HDD or a SSD.

Comment: But possibly the files it needs are located in the C drive (with the windows files) and it is looking in the e drive?

Comment: Is there a "E:\Program Files\MSBuild" or "E:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" directory?  Did that directory get put onto drive C: even though you asked VC++ Express to install to E:?

Comment: I'd actually recommend installing it on the C drive, especially if it's an SSD - the builds will be way faster with that. :) And in general I'd recommend installing Microsoft stuff on the same drive as the OS, since they tend to not really work so well on other drives.. in my experience at least.

Comment: @Insilico I know that a SDD or HDD does not matter but my concern is that the files may have been installed elsewhere or already existed with my windows files on the C drive and the Visual Express install on my E drive is having troubles locating the files in a different drive for whatever reason.

Comment: @MichaelBurr It is not there, no matter how many times I install.

Comment: @Xeo I would really prefer it not to be on my SDD since I do not have much space on it, but I will try and install it on there now to see if it works. Also I don't think my 9 lines of cout code is going to take long to compile and run anyways.

Comment: I installed it on the C drive and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Xeo Not in my experience - the build of any large program is hardly ever IO limited. Eg compiling the whole hotspot source code takes a good bit of time, but in the end we don't write that much data to it (and reading is largely sequential and can be buffered). Also I've Visual Studio 08 installed on my G drive (VS2010 is on the ssd on C) and it has absolutely no problems. Seems like something botched the install - just do it again (and before that make sure that the download was successful, ie compare hashes!)

Comment: Did you install it as an administrator? Do you run it as an administrator?

Comment: Please improve your title. As written, it will not be useful to others.

Comment: @Bart I am doing everything as an admin.

Comment: I'm starting to believe that you're cursed. o_o Normally, just starting the installer and clicking "next" till the end should be enough to get a working installation, it's really straight forward. Best of luck with this problem!

Comment: @Xeo Where else can I look for help? I am out of ideas.

Comment: @Jordan: you say both "That directory is in E" and "It is not there, no matter how many times I install", so I'm not sure if there is an "MSBuild" directory or where it is.  Also, in your error message quote, the path being complained about is "E:..........\MSBuild\Microsoft.cpp\v4.0\Platforms" - is that actually the error (with the dots and all) or are you paraphrasing? If the error message you put in the question isn't *exactly* the error message given, you might want to update the question with the exact error message (note that Ctrl-C will copy the messagebox text to the clipboard).

Comment: ---------------------------
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express
---------------------------
The platforms root directory "E:\Program Files                           (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms" does not exist.                                       
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------                                                             The microsoft.cpp part is missing but it exists in the C drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since - as you've pointed out - you've already reinstalled VC++ and nothing seems to work and you've tried everything - you may also try this (if you've not given up yet):

1. you may try trial version of full visual studio [VS2010 trial](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/try)
2. you may try to install your VS express on friends PC on 'non-C' drive
3. perform antivirus check of your system
4. after installing full version - install service pack ([VS SP](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691))
5. ensure you uninstall all (if any) prior versions of VC, VB, VC# or visual studion that you may have
6. always reboot after installation

If (1) works this may suggest your VS express is somehow corrupted (would be weird to be able install it than - but I've seen so many weird things that I may believe it ;-)
If (2) works this may suggest your PC/OS is causing problems.

Let me/us know if any of above helps.

Comment: All excellent suggestions, Atur.  In general, VS2010 "just works".  But if you're installing on something other than a "normal" hard drive (C: or D:, for example), you're asking for trouble.  You *MUST* uninstall any *PREVIOUS* versions of MSVS (and reboot!) first ... or you're asking for trouble.  Failing all else: try installing on a friend's PC.

Comment: @paulsm4: As for friend's PC - it was just to verify if Jordan's install CD/DVD/ISO (whatever) is not corrupted in any way. If he manages to install it on his friends E drive (similar scenario as his) it may suggest to get rid of his 'crappy' CD/DVD... and get new one ;-)

Comment: I am installing it from the Microsoft website, I have no idea what to do anymore I still can't get this to work.

Comment: @Artur I have a bunch of Microsoft Visual C++ 2008/2010 Redistributable files in my unistall manager. Should I get rid of them too or leave them alone?

Comment: @Jordan: You can leave redistributables. As for installation - better download ISO first (in cae you'll try to install more than once) and get MagicISO to mount.

Comment: @Artur Microsoft SQL 2008 failed to install, is that important? Also I installed the VS2010 trial and I have the same exacty error.

Comment: In the last resort - Format your drives, reinstall system, install full trial on C as others have suggested. It should fit on C if you uncheck Visual Basic, C#, F# and SQL. If it does not fit - try unplugging your SSD, leave it on the desk and install everything (system+VS) on regular magnetic drive. If that will not work for you I have no ideas and cannot help you - get someone else install it for you. But do not worry - I have once seen myself a guy whose Windows was not booting up (really) when while pushing power up button his monitor's power cord was plugged into the power socket :-D.

Answer (score 0):

1. I would uninstall and reinstall the whole thing rather than keep spinning your wheels.  Honest!
2. Q: Your "E:" drive is a read-write drive, isn't it?

   Q: E: is the drive you installed to, correct?

   Q: Hopefully, E: is a normal disk drive, isn't it?
   If not (if it's a shared network drive, or a nice'n'slow USB drive), please consider installing VS2010 to a hard drive.
3. MSVS should *not* be hard to install or use.  It takes awhile ... but it's usually pretty straightforward.

   If you've having problems, then I *strongly* urge you to 1) uninstall, 2) reboot, 3) reinstall.

IMHO...

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. I did 1 2 and 3 about a dozen times already.

Comment: @Jordan, I've installed Visual Studio on dozens and dozens of machines, and never had anything near the problems you are seeing. I hate to suggest this because it's a ton of work, but I'd suggest flattening your whole machine at this point, and doing a fresh install of windows from scratch. If the installation of VS is having this many problems then there may be something seriously screwed up on your machine: malware, corrupted system files, beta software, etc.

Comment: @Charles I am not really willing to do that as it would take a week or so to get my computer back to where I have it now.

Comment: @Jordan, very painful I know, but how many hours have you already put into solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69925677-8a07-46a4-8b0e-c9ddef17a7af/visual-studio-2010-fails-in-c-trying-to-set-the-references-parameter?forum=vssetup

The solution in a similar case of installing VS2010 C# on a seperate drive was to copy the Reference Assemblies folder from C:\Program Files to E:\Program Files.

When I had the the same error as the poster above on VS2010 C++, when installing to a different drive, I did the same for the MSBuild Directory and the errors in VS2010 C++ disappeared.

It seems that Visual Studio installs/creates those directories on the same drive as windows 100% of the time, but the registry values still look for them on the same drive that you installed Visual Studio on.